# javascript how to remove loading gif from tbody table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding rows with javascript to this tbody

```
<div id="listingContainer"><div id="listing"><table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="listingTable"><tbody id="places"><img src="images/loading.gif"></tbody></table></div></div>
```

I tried this:

```
$("#places").html('');
```

but is adding to it

http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/2JTPD/

Comment: `tbody` does not accepts `img` tag as child element.

Comment: anything besides <tr> is invalid html for direct descendants of tbody, the browser compensates by removing it from there. Open the dev tools and take a look at the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll need your `<img>` tag to be within a `<td>` tag. Then use `remove();` to get rid of the image like so:

HTML:

```
<tbody id="places">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src=".../loading.gif">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#places img").remove();
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2JTPD/29/

Comment: @Sebastian Good to hear!

Answer (score 3):

It does not work cause

`tbody` does not accepts `img` tag as child element.

This is an example of valid `table` markup. Act accordingly

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="places">
         <img src="loading.gif">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<sub>**Note:** The `tbody` is not necessary</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/chace/2JTPD/28/

```
window.setTimeout(blahFunc,5000)

function blahFunc() {
    $("#places").html('done');
}
```